# Has and have with present and past perfect

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use have or has in the following sentences?
1/ Does he has/have to take the responsibility?
2/ Does he has/have gone outside the country?
3/ Did he had paint the wall before you come?
I mean when we use have/ has in question  with present perfec and past perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word ordering is incorrect, which might be part of the confusion. Do/does/did is not necessarily correct for have/has. These are correct sentences:

1. Does he have to take the responsibility? (Better: Must he... or Is he required to...)
2. Has he gone... or Did he go... .
3. Did he paint... or Had he painted... .